# How can I change the value of child in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to change the value of child "toggleStatus" under Reference "BetSlip" as shown below. The already set value is "on" so I want such that when I click the button the value of "toggleStatus" is changed to "off"

```
BetSlipActivity.toggleCollapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String timeStamp = betSlip.get(position).getTimeStamp();
        String toggleStatus = betSlip.get(position).getToggleStatus();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BetSlip");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String timestamp = ""+ ds.child("timeStamp").getValue();
                    String toggleStatus = ""+ ds.child("toggleStatus").getValue();
                    if (timeStamp.equals(timestamp) && toggleStatus.equals("on")) {
                        //set value to off
                    }
                    if (timeStamp.equals(timestamp) && toggleStatus.equals("off")) {
                        //set value to on
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image: This is how the database looks like]

Comment: There are multiple child nodes under `/BetSlip`. Which one(s) do you want to update? Never mind, I see you already determine that. I'll answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the `DataSnapshot` for a path in the database, it's easy to get the `DatabaseReference` that you need to update it:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("BetSlip");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String timestamp = ""+ ds.child("timeStamp").getValue();
            String toggleStatus = ""+ ds.child("toggleStatus").getValue();
            if (timeStamp.equals(timestamp) && toggleStatus.equals("on")) {
                ds.child("toggleStatus").getRef().setValue("off");
            }
            if (timeStamp.equals(timestamp) && toggleStatus.equals("off")) {
                ds.child("toggleStatus").getRef().setValue("on");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Since you're updating the node based on its existing value, strictly speaking you might need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) for it.